# Testing newly injected content with Rspec and Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, rspec, capybara

We're using react components in our Rails views, one of which when a button is clicked renders another component in its place.

Ideally we want to back these up with Rspec feature tests but when the button is clicked and the new component is renders the value of `page` isn't updated to reflect this.

Is there a way with Rspec/Capybara to get the newly injected content after the new react component as rendered?

Here's the snippet:

```
scenario 'users should be able to move to step 2', js: true do
  sign_in_with 'test@test.com', 'testpassword'
  visit new_path
  fill_in 'name', with: 'Test'
  select "Category One", :from => "dropdown"
  click_button 'Next'
  expect(page).to have_content('New Content')
end
```

Comment: what capybara driver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Capybara actually **should** update `page` with any JS logic (if everything is set correctly). More info:

- https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#asynchronous-javascript-ajax-and-friends
- https://robots.thoughtbot.com/write-reliable-asynchronous-integration-tests-with-capybara

What is happening on click on `Next`? Is it smth time consuming? (then you may need to prolong capybara wait timeout)

To debug it further you may want to run tests with visible browser or take screenshots in case of failure to see actual page content (ex. https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot)

Comment: It's not time consuming when clicking next it just renders changes the state of the component to render something else, so it causes the html to change from what it was originally to something new.  I'm using webkit driver btw.

Answer (score 0):

`page` is just a shortcut for `Capybara.current_session`, there is no cache or anything that would prevent it from showing the current state of the page.  This would tend to indicate you're not checking for the correct changed info, or the info on the page isn't actually changing when you click the button.  The most common reason for the info not changing would be a JS error which you can check by looking at `page.driver.error_messages` after clicking the button. The most common reasons for that error, on a page that works fine when you manually test it in a browser, would be building capybara-webkit with an old version of Qt or using ES6 features (without transpiling) that aren't supported by the latest version of Qt capybara-webkit works with.  You want to make sure you've built capybara-webkit with Qt 5.5.x and if it still doesn't work then check the `page.driver.error_messages` mentioned before to see what errors are being raised.